# Does not display anything after data entry

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Does not display anything after data entry

```
program g
implicit none
    real::q,n,s,z,q2,y,free_board,r,b,e,A,h,t
    write(*,100)"pls insert discharge Q ="
    read(*,*)q
    write(*,100)"please insert Manning coefficient n ="
    read(*,*)n
    write(*,*)"please insert slope of the hydraulic channel ="
    read(*,*)s
    write(*,*)"please inset Z ="
    read(*,*)z
    write(*,*)"how much of b/y do you want?"
    write(*,*)"if it not important right 2.5"
    read(*,*)e
    if(e<2.or.e>5)then
        stop
    end if
    y=0

    do
        b=y*e
        A=b+2*y*((1+Z**2)**(0.5))
        R=((b+z*y)*y)/(b+(2*y*(1+z**2)**(0.5)))
        h=(1/n)*(r**(2/3))*A*(s)**0.5
       if( abs(h-q)<0.01) then
        exit
       end if




       y=0.001+y
    end do
    free_board=0.2*y
    h=free_board+y
    t=b+2*y*z


    write(*,100)"free board="
    write(*,*) free_board
    write(*,100)"y="
    write(*,*)y
    write(*,100)"b="
    write(*,*)b
    write(*,100)"T="
    write(*,100)t














    100 format(A)
end program g
```

this not work and not show anything after enter data

Comment: Please show your input values and the output you do see as well as the value of `e` just after you have read it.

Comment: r**(2/3) - is this really what you mean? You are doing integer division so this will always evaluate to r**0=1. I suspect you want r**(2.0/3.0)

Answer (score 0):

For sure the line `write(*,100)t` will give you a wrong output, since "t" it is a real, not a string. Please change it to `write(*,*)`.

With all inputs equal to 1.0 and by putting e=2.5, I see these output (at screen):

- free board = 3.7200041E-02
- y = 0.1860002
- b = 0.4650005
- T = 0.8370009

If you don't see outputs, maybe you are choosing wrong "e" values (less than 2 or more than 5).